# How do I add In-Reply-To and References to 'Send mail'?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My feature was built before `/createReply` existed and relies on:

[Set a custom header with Outlook/Office 365 REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214197/set-a-custom-header-with-outlook-office-365-rest%20#)

to add `References` and `In-Reply-To` to an email. This allows the app to send email replies w/o requiring `Mail.ReadWrite`, which is much more access than we need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions

> Read and write access to user mail
>
> Allows the app to create, read, update, and delete email in user mailboxes. Does not include permission to send mail.

Now those headers no longer get added. (I also tried [Cannot pass "In-Reply-To" parameter to Microsoft Graph sendMail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55945615/2204868) and arrived at the same result as the author.)

Is there a way for me to get around this regression without requesting additional user permission? Thanks!

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019-10-04, Microsoft published changes to their `/reply` endpoint which now allows for `message`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/5771

With the `message` field, I should be able to send replies w/o requesting additional permissions.