# Microsoft Graph: How to send emails in the same thread, without needing a client's reply first

Tags: javascript, email, microsoft-graph-api, request-headers

Is there a way to send an email via Microsoft Graph with `references` or `in-reply-to` headers applied?

I've looked at

- [Cannot pass "In-Reply-To" parameter to Microsoft Graph sendMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945615/cannot-pass-in-reply-to-parameter-to-microsoft-graph-sendmail)
- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6256
- [How do I add In-Reply-To and References to 'Send mail'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532471/how-do-i-add-in-reply-to-and-references-to-send-mail/58546651#58546651)

All of these seem to address when replying to a client's response. E.g.) User sends an email to client >> Client sends a reply back >> User sends a reply.

I need a way to thread the emails even if I send them 2 emails back to back. E.g.) User sends an email to client >> User sends a follow up email to client.

Microsoft Graph API's `reply` endpoints seems to overwrite any `toRecipient` you pass through, and automatically will send the email to the Sender of the previous email:

> Reply to the sender of a message using either JSON or MIME format.
>
> - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

So if I were to...

From: me@hotmail.com

To: client@gmail.com

1. Send the initial email via `/me/messages/{id}/send`
2. Then immediately send a follow up email via `/me/messages/{id}/reply`,

It just sends up sending the reply to myself, me@hotmail.com; since Microsoft Graph specifically states that it replies to the sender. In this instance, I'm just replying to my own message.

Comment: Did you managed to solved this?

Answer (score 0):

The Send message endpoint sends an existing draft message.

The draft message today can be a new message draft, reply draft, reply-all draft, or a forward draft. Refer documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Being said that, consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so it could be considered for future implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for a solution...

You can use the following steps.

1. Assuming you have access to the first message sent that has no reply, save the message ID (save some headache and use ImmutableIds if you haven't), conversationId, and the internetMessageId.
2. Create a draft reply with createReply. The message ID will be required and you will include the internetMessageId in the In-Reply-To header.
3. If this is done correctly then the conversationId for both the original message and the draft reply will be the same.
4. Send the draft reply via its message ID.